# Fix position of sliding contetnt button

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have used this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tricki/vVSJz/4/) logic to make a sliding drawer. Need to make the click panel fixed.

I changed some CSS properties

```
#panel-tab{
  position:fixed;
}
```

Also tried giving

```
#panel{
    position:fixed
}
```

But on scroll of document it doesn't remain fixed. Why isn't position:fixed not functioning as per its usual behavior?

Comment: working fine for me with fixed

Comment: I tried your code, and it's working [check fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vVSJz/663/)

Comment: Solved the issue. It was not working since the div was inside the carousel div.